# Decomposing a Term in a Lagrangian by Transformation Properties

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, field-theory

In the literature on effective field theories, one might see statements like ''Term X in the Lagrangian is Lorentz invariant but spontaneously violates diffeomorphism invariance''.

When such a statement is made, does this mean it is possible to separate out the term into a sum of two terms, the one which is Lorentz invariant and the other which is invariant (or not invariant) under diffeomorphisms?